# How do meshes, sub-meshes, materials, sub-materials, textures all relate to each other

Tags: 3d

What bothers me is that I can't figure out **how exactly meshes, materials, textures actually relate** to the composition of a model.

All I want is a quick explanation on how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

**Mesh** - it's just some object that you want to draw, like a car. It can be built of many sub-objects, but for simplicity and ease of use it's implemented as one object wrapping all you need. E.g.: when you want to put a car on your level you typically don't want to place every wheel/tire separately - so you have just one mesh: 'a car'.

**Sub-mesh** - when you render some polygons list you need to setup some way of performing your operations (this is called material), before you start rendering. This means that you can't use more than one material during single rendering operation. Because a car is made of many different materials like glass, metal, etc. you need it to be divided into submeshes. You'll have submesh for windows, tires, wheels and the body - each of them will use different material like glass, rubber, aluminium, etc. and each will be rendered in different render operation, with different material selected. So a material definition isn't stored in mesh object but in every submesh.

**Material** - it's a definition of 'what to do when adding new triangle to the screen', it may vary between engines and underlying API version but it just stores all the parameters you may set for your material, like opacity, glossiness, color (texture), pixel/vertex shaders, etc.

**Texture** - material can use images as an input 2D/3D data. When you read your material definition it has the image file names defined, the images are read and put into your GPU with some ID assigned. Later, when you select the material the GPU will use correct textures by their ID and I think that's all you need to know for now :)

I can't help you with sub-materials as I think it's highly engine-dependent, if you tell us what are you using we may be able to tell you more.

Comment: I'm attempting to build my own basic engine in Haxe (avoiding AS3 for the lack of optimization). But I understand it now, thanks. Material is what the system reads and provides a shader to render that information. Sub-mesh is geometry for each material.